# jQuery toggleClass and slideToggle

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I'm toggling a class that hides and unhides a div within a list item, but I'm having problems applying a slideToggle to it.

Here is the HTML and CSS;

```
<style>
.collapsed .widget-content {
display:none !important;
}
</style>

        <ul id="column1" class="column">
        <li class="widget color-green" id="intro">
            <div class="widget-head">
            <a class="collapse" href"#">collapse</a>
                <h3>The Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
                <p>content here</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Here is the jQuery to toggle the class of the li on click on the link with the class "collapse"

```
       $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).toggleClass('collapsed');
```

How do I apply the slideToggle so that it only slides away the "widget-content" div whilst toggling the "collapsed" class on the li at the same time?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

you could try a callback when the toggle is complete:

```
$(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).slideToggle('slow', function() {
     $('#intro').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

something like that?

Comment: yeah that pretty close. I ended up having to rework the code a bit due to other implications in the script. Thanks for putting me on the right track.